# Can I put a CGI program in place of index.html so as to Not respond to referer (sic) spammers?

Tags: apache, cgi, spam-prevention, referer, web-traffic

I want to put a CGI program in place of index.html so as to Not respond to referer spammers, and thus not in-turn spam the spoofed IP address they supply.  My sites get spammed by referer spammers (eg rankings-analytics) and I'm aware that my Apache will respond with the index.html.  But of course where it sends it is to some poor unsuspecting IP address supplied by the spammer that also doesn't want to be spammed, and will think it's my site doing it (which is even worse).

But how do I do that please?

Comment: Why not use a service such as spamhaus?

Comment: Because I want my own server to decide whether to respond or not, not cause extra internet traffic by consulting another server.  Also, I don't think "spamhaus" blacklisting (or Block List'ing) various IP addresses commandeered in a DOS attack is really fair.  But thanks for the suggestion.